# How do I SSH on a network where IP addresses are blocked?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ip, ssh-tunnel

I'm on a network where direct access to any IP address is blocked. Because of this, I cannot ssh to any machine whatsoever. How do I bypass this? No VPN is working, no proxy (again an IP), no SOCK5 (again needs SSH) is working. How do I bypass this?

Even when I ssh like: ssh root@mymachine.com it does not work because I think mymachine.com is first resolved to IP and then connected which is banned.

[image]

and ssh: (works fine on any other internet connection)

[image]

Comment: What is allowed then?

Comment: @sebix access to only domains directly. Like google is allowed only from google.com and not from 172.217.26.238

Comment: Your computer resolves the Domain to the IP, always. This is how intenet works.

Comment: @sebix I know, but they somehow block access if I directly access IP address. Maybe they detect if a request does not go through their DNS resolver then block it?

Comment: @sebix I updated the answer with the message I get

Comment: @sebix it is probably cyberroam

Comment: Concerning your first screenshot: They probably intercept HTTP and then block any hostname with an IP. For the second: there are thousands of possible reasons...

Comment: Hey dude. I don't think there is any super tricky stuff happening here. The network admin have probably blocked all traffic, and whitelisted google.com / amazon.com etc. That means that when google.com resolves to IP, they're allowed through. Try some other random dot com and see if that works? As such, you'll probably need to either get the IP of your box whitelisted, or see if there is another network you can join that is less strict.

Comment: @llorrac every domain works except some specific ones (for instance hotspotshield.com is blocked, kproxy.com, skype.com (and client) is blocked, etc.) I registered a new domain name here and it works too.

Comment: There's a difference between the HTTP/HTTPS blocking of ip addresses in sites and the SSH failures. Please don't assume they're related issues. You're going to have to have a chat with your networking folks about the SSH issue, as for us to guess over and over again will not be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have IP connectivity you won't be able to use any protocols that rely on it.

Comment: but access is allowed to only domains directly. Like google is allowed only from google.com and not from 172.217.26.238

Comment: It looks like a proxy server doing that filtering on web traffic. It's probably a different reason why you can't ssh out, that is probably not working because you don't have port 22 allowed outbound.

Comment: i tried to setup ssh on different port but it still doesn't work

Comment: To put it another way you are probably only permitted outbound access on port 80 and 443, and that traffic is being filtered. Have you thought about submitting a request for access to whoever manages the network?

Comment: Take a look at `corkscrew` to tunnel through the HTP proxy.